# make all error while installing htk

Tags: 13.04, software-installation

I am getting error in make all while installing `htk` :

```
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dushyant/HTK/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from HShell.h:40,
                 from HGraf.c:54:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dushyant/HTK/htk/HTKLib'
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

What should I do ?

Comment: The file in question (`bits/predefs.h`) is from the package `libc6-dev` (install with `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`).

Comment: I have the same problem with ubuntu 14.04.
Anyone found something?

Comment: same issue, 16.04 :/ any luck mate?

Answer (score 1):

That header `bits/predefs.h` comes with `libc6-dev-i386` (32bit headers). Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

Reference: [Missing predefs.h](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877944)